# Converting Int to CGFloat results in 0.000000

Tags: ios, swift, int, uicolor, cgfloat

I am attempting to take `Int` values from an Array and convert them into `CGFloat`s so that I may create a `UIColor` from those red, green, and blue values. Simple enough, right?

I can successfully get the `Int` values out of the array, but when I attempt to convert to `CGFloat`, the result is 0.000000. Why is this?

```
let colorArray = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey("colors")
let redValue = colorArray[0] as Int
let greenValue = colorArray[1] as Int
let blueValue = colorArray[2] as Int
NSLog("%i", redValue) //prints 255
NSLog("%i", greenValue) //prints 250
NSLog("%i", blueValue) //prints 150
let redFloat = CGFloat(redValue) / 255.0
let greenFloat = CGFloat(greenValue) / 255.0
let blueFloat = CGFloat(blueValue) / 255.0
NSLog("%f", redFloat) //prints 0.000000
let color = UIColor(red: redFloat, green: greenFloat, blue: blueFloat, alpha: 1)
```

If I don't divide by 255.0 I get the same result - 0. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a weird problem with Foundation string formatting and conversion from `CGFloat`. The same problem occurs with `NSString(format:_:)`. If you use `NSLog("%f", redFloat.native)` or `print("\(redFloat)")` or just `print(redFloat)` there are no problems.

Comment: Perhaps the CGFloat is not correctly passed on the variable argument list. - This seems to be worth a bug report at Apple.

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me; beta 4 had a bunch of CGFloat changes. Yup, file a Radar.