# How to truncate CGFloat values?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

since I've noticed that `Float` and `CGFloat` behave differently on 32-bit and 64-bit devices, which could lead to bugs, I try to substitute all `Float` values with `CGFloat` in my project. However I couldn't figure out a way to truncate `CGfloat` values to 2 digits after the decimal point.

In my project I have a function that download files returns a `Float` value "progress" constantly, indicating how many percent of the total files has been downloaded, which is usually something like "0.3942183693039206". In this case, I need to truncate the number to "0.39" so I can make update to the UI, and here is my function:

```
    func updatePropertiesForPorgress(progress:CGFloat){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
        let truncated = NSString(format: "%.2f", progress)
        let float = truncated.floatValue
        self.progressTileView.rating = CGFloat(float)
    })
}
```

It works perfectly fine with `Float` values, but if I pass progress as a `CGFloat` value, the truncated variable would equal to "0.00":
[image]
[image]

Out of curiosity, I tried to replicate the situation in playground, and did it successfully. Code as simple as:

```
var test:CGFloat = 0.3920394829459
let truncated = NSString(format: "%.2f", test)
let float = truncated.floatValue
```

would have different output depending on "test" variable being a `Float` or a `CGFloat` value. If "test" is a `Float` value, the result would be 0.39, which is correct, but if I change it to a `CGFloat`, the result would be "0.00".

Can anyone help me understand what's happening, and show me how to truncate `CGFloat` values correctly? I tried `NSNumberFormatter` but it didn't work(for now).

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the same rounding can simply be achieved with `let float = round(100.0 * Float(progress))/100.0`, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328615/is-there-an-efficient-way-to-round-a-float-to-the-nearest-hundredths-place-in-sw.

Comment: You should also be aware that none of the floating point types Float/Double/CGFloat can represent the number 0.39 *exactly*, due to the binary representation used by these types. The result of your computation is actually 0.38999998569488525391, but println() limits the output precision to six decimal digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSString(format:_: ...)` accepts `CVarArgType`s:

```
extension NSString {
    convenience init(format: NSString, _ args: CVarArgType...)
```

But, as of Swift 1.1, `CGFloat` itself does not conforms to `CVarArgType`. When it passed to `NSString(format:_: ...)`, it is converted to `NSNumber`.

So `NSString(format: "%.2f", test)` is equivalent to `NSString(format: "%.2f", test as NSNumber)`. As a result, `%.2f` would be `0.00`

You should explicitly convert it to `Double`:

```
NSString(format: "%.2f", Double(test))
```

---

Note that: as of Swift 1.2, Since `CGFloat` conforms to `CVarArgType`, your code works as is.

Comment: Same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098678/converting-int-to-cgfloat-results-in-0-000000, but your answer explains it better. Not sure if we should close as a duplicate.