# Why does NSLog show screen width and screen height as 0?

Tags: ios, swift

So I wrote the following piece of code, which displays the red square in the middle, as I intended to be. However, when I "NSLog"ed the output of the screen size of the device onto the console, I found that the value is 0. Why is that?

```
let container = UIView()
let redSquare = UIView()
let blueSquare = UIView()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    let screenSize : CGSize = UIScreen.mainScreen().applicationFrame.size
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height

    NSLog("screenWidth = %f, screenHeight = %f", screenWidth, screenHeight);
    self.container.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: screenWidth-100, height: screenWidth-100)

    self.view.addSubview(container)

    // set red square frame up
    // we want the blue square to have the same position as redSquare
    // so lets just reuse blueSquare.frame
    self.redSquare.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth-100, height: screenWidth-100)
    self.blueSquare.frame = redSquare.frame

    // set background colors
    self.redSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.blueSquare.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    // for now just add the redSquare
    // we'll add blueSquare as part of the transition animation
    self.container.addSubview(self.redSquare)

}
```

Comment: Frankly, I don't know, but try using Swift's notation to see if it changes something: `NSLog("screenWidth = \(screenWidth), screenHeight = \(screenHeight)")`. Also, you don't really _need_ that `;` at the end anymore;)

Comment: @Romain that totally worked! I see that it's all about optionals now.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/29404849/3804019

Comment: Linked question is for `NSString(format:_:)`, but the same reason. use `NSLog("screenWidth = %f, screenHeight = %f", Double(screenWidth), Double(screenHeight))` instead.